# Running Tasks on Windows IOT

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-10-iot-core

i want to schedule a task on Windows IOT. With this task i want to execute a bat file.

I have already tested my batch file directly and it is working without any issue. Furthermore all the path entries in the script are complete so that i can assure it is proper executing from any directory.
Additionally the batch file is also translated to ANSI.

When i start my task manually from the console i get the following response:

```
ActivityId:{B575CA4C-A160-4A8A-BDCD-596D20CB63B7}, InstanceId:"B575CA4C-A160-4A8A-BDCD-596D20CB63B7", Message:Failed to format message, OpCode:0, RelatedActivityId:{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, UserContext:"Administrator",
```

OpCode 0 means in my opinion "Success".
However the script is not executed at all.

Does anyone of has a clue regarding the message "Failed to format message"?
Or has any other hints where to look?

Thanks,
Florian

My Batchfile is just one line:
U:\dotnet\dotnet U:\script\ShortSuperStar.dll > U:\script\log.txt

Comment: Is ShortSuperStar.dll something that you wrote? There are no results when I search Google for it. If you wrote it, we need to see that code as well, since that's where the error is.

Comment: How do you schedule it? How do you know it doesn't work? Do system logs contain anything related?

Comment: sorry ShortSuperstar.dll is my own programm that i want to start.

Comment: And the system log is exactly what i copied above. I do not see any other information than the one above.

Comment: This is how i scheduled the task on power shell: SCHTASKS / Create / SC DAILY / TN test2 / TR U:\directory\start.bat / ST 08:15 / ET 03:00 / K

Comment: seems that i missed some paramters. With the following command it does work successfully

Comment: OT: You can create chart images with MSChart from a Console app fine; but I'm not sure about VS code.